# Camel always routing messages to 0 partition of intended Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

My use case: Given, one JMS queue, one Kafka topic with two partitions,
route messages from JMS queue to a particular partition of the Kafka topic based on custom header attribute's value.

Problem: Messages are getting routed from JMS to Kafka Topic's partition 0, not to partition 1
even though **PARTITION_KEY** and **KEY** are set in headers (code below).

Dependencies with version **2.16.3** used, steps and java code attempted is below:

---

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId> <!--**2.16.3** used-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <!--**2.16.3** used-->
  <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <!--**2.16.3** used-->
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>            
</dependency>
```

---

1. Created a Kafka topic with two partitions:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:218 1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic mytopic-with-partitions
```

2. Listen to messages on Partition 0:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopic-with-partitions --partition 0
```

3. Listen to messages on Partition 1:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopic-with-partitions --partition 1
```

---

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder
{
    private final MessagePreprocessor messagePreProcessor = new MessagePreprocessor();
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
     from("jms:queue:my-jms-queue").process(messagePreProcessor)
            .log("Routing message from my-jms-queue to " + toKafka)
            .to("kafka:localhost:9092?mytopic-with-partitions&zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181&serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
       
    }
}
```

=============================

```
public class MessagePreprocessor implements Processor
{
    @Override
    public void process(final Exchange exchange)
    {
        final String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        exchange.getOut().setBody(body);

        Integer partitionToUse = 0;

        final String flavorGot = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("FLAVOR");
        if ("VANILLA".equals(flavorGot)) {
           partitionToUse = 0;
        } else {
           partitionToUse = 1;
        }
        
        
        headers.put(KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY, partitionToUse);
        headers.put(KafkaConstants.KEY, flavorGot);

        exchange.getOut().setHeaders(headers);
    }

}
```

---

Output:

1. Messages are making it to Partition 0, displayed by command in Step 2
2. Messages are **NOT** making it to Partition 1, displayed by command in Step 3.

Appreciate any suggestions/pointers. Thanks

Comment: Is `KafkaConstants.KEY` just a Camel header? Or is that used as the Kafka message key? And can you add log statements to see what your inputs and headers actually get set to?

Comment: Yes `KafkaConstants.KEY` is just Camel header as listed in `MessagePreprocessor`
```headers.put(KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY, partitionToUse);
        headers.put(KafkaConstants.KEY, flavorGot);
```
I verified the headers are set as intended and do not see any errors. Surprised what is missing. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Camel but I find it strange that you'd need to set both a key and a partition, when Kafka will route the data based on the key by itself.

Comment: Per documentation of camel-kafka component at https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html,
my confusion/understanding is `PARTITION_KEY` required to tell which partition to route to and `KEY` tells which message. Not sure if that is my problem. Thanks